# c++ passing class instance as float variable in libconfig++ :: lookupValue()

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, libconfig

I have this small class that revolves around a single double variable

```
class SensorTrainData
{
    public:
        SensorTrainData() : trainingRangeFactor(2.0f) {}
        SensorTrainData( const double & _factor ) { setFactor(_factor); }

        SensorTrainData & operator=(const double& other)
        {
             setFactor(other);
             return *this;
         }

         operator double() const
         {
             return getFactor();
         }

    private:

        void setFactor( const double & factor );
        const double & getFactor() const { return trainingRangeFactor; }

        double trainingRangeFactor; 
};
```

These user function `double()`  and the operator "=" overload allow me to do respectively

```
SensorTrainData std(3.0f);
double d = std;

double k = 4.0f;
std = k;
```

I am using `libconfig++` and I want to be able to pass the variable `std` directly in the `libconfig::lookupValue("varName" , std)` in order to pick value "varName", which was read in from a config (text) file.

Unfortunately, the compiler says I cannot pass a `SensorTrainData &` .

```
src/sensor.cpp:1048:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘libconfig::Setting::lookupValue(const char [12], enalu::SensorTrainData&) const’
src/sensor.cpp:1048:45: note: candidates are:
...
....
/usr/include/libconfig.h++:255:8: note: bool libconfig::Setting::lookupValue(const char*, double&) const
/usr/include/libconfig.h++:255:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘enalu::SensorTrainData’ to ‘double&’
```

of course I could do

```
double foo = 0.0f;
libconfig::lookupValue("varName" , foo); //load varName from file into foo
std = foo;
```

But I want to avoid the extra typing and code lines etc.

IS there an operator overload trick I could use to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about const-ness: you're trying to convert `std` to a non-const reference while your `operator double` is const and relies on `getFactor` which returns a const reference.

The following code works as intended:

```
class SensorTrainData
{
    public:
        SensorTrainData() : trainingRangeFactor(2.0f) {}
        SensorTrainData( const double & _factor ) { setFactor(_factor); }

        SensorTrainData & operator=(const double& other)
        {
            setFactor(other);
            return *this;
        }

        operator double&()
        {
            return getFactor();
        }

    private:

        void setFactor( const double & factor ) { trainingRangeFactor = factor; }
        double & getFactor() { return trainingRangeFactor; }

        double trainingRangeFactor; 
};
```

The obvious drawback is that you're now exposing `trainingRangeFactor` as a non-const reference.